# Angular redirect after refresh and block access via direct url

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

On my website you can manage a list of users and when you click on edit it redirects you to the /edit-user page where informations are preload in a form.

When you refresh the page with F5, it reloads the page but without the informations because I use informations that are in my store and I don't want to call my api here or store the information in the localstorage.

I would like the redirect people who refresh or tries to access this page via direct url on my first page where there is the users list.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In `/edit-user page` constructor put below code. When you refresh or load page directly, the previous URL will not be available. So, if the previous URL is not available or other than user list, redirect.

```
previousUrl: string;

constructor(router: Router) {
  router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log('prev:', this.previousUrl);
    // if previous URL is empty or other than user list then redirect to your first page
    this.previousUrl = e.url;
  });
}
```

Comment: it says that error: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for you with the refresh here is, that you're trying to load a page with no information in the store.

So, I would advise you to check if the information is NOT present (undefined or whatever), to redirect the user or block access however you see fit.

Comment: The problem is that i use this page for creating a user so it's not a problem if the information is not present. The problem would be, the information isn't present and i'm on the edit-user url and not the create-user url

Comment: It doesn't really matter, what is meant by information. You can create additional "information". For example, if you need the user to be able to enter the page from a specific place only, you can set some sort of a flag and pass that information along, then check if that information is present.

Comment: In any case, this is as far as I can go without seeing some code, or better yet an example

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help :), i will try to add a flag ^^

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found is to test the selector i had in my constructor.

If the constructor return no information, it sure i don't come from the last page but i tried to refresh via F5 or access the page via direct URL.

```
      this.fetchUsersSubscription = this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
          this.userId = Number(params.get('userId'));
          return merge(
            this.usersSelector.getUsers().pipe(
              map((users: User[]) => {
                if (users) {
                  // do what you want
                  });
                } else {
                  this.router.navigate(['your url'])
                  // this block the refresh or the direct url access via rerouting
                }
              })
            )
          );
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
```

The idea come from the suggestions from Javid Askerov and Soham.